# Cannot use "Observable.Of(value)"

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, angular6, rxjs6

I'm migrating my app from **Angular 5.2.9** to **Angular 6.0.4**

I ve upgraded from **rxjs v5** to **v6**
And I've uninstalled : **rxjs-compat** (as I was told that it's no more needed)

So in the old syntax, I was used to return custom observable like this:

```
  public myObservable() {
    return Observable.of(true);
  }
```

It seems that this syntax is no more usefull as there is no more the operator **"of"**

the error is the following:

> error TS2339: Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   Observable'.

So what is the alternative? 
**Suggestions?**

Comment: import of from 'rxjs'

Answer (score 1):

You just need to directly import it from `rxjs`.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import `of` operator separately, like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```